# SQL query num rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query that gets the max of a column.  I need to check if the results returns 0 or not.  If 0 rows i need to execute some code else execute some code.  I put an echo in my if to see if it is being hit (it should be because there are no records in the table I am executing the query against) but it is not displaying the echo.  Below is my code:

```
$sellOrSearch = $_POST['optionsDropDown'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbnNum'];
$price = $_POST['bookPrice'];
$condition = $_POST['bookCondition'];
$desc = $_POST['descTextArea'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$lineNumber = 0;
$maxLineNumber = 0;

$lineNumberQuery = "SELECT MAX(lineNumber) " .
          "FROM INVENTORY_BOOK " .
          "WHERE studentEmail = '$email'";

$lineNumberQueryResult = mysql_query($lineNumberQuery) or
         die("Error accessing Customer table for email look up: " .       mysql_error());

$numRows = mysql_numrows($lineNumberQueryResult);
if($numRows == 0)
{
$lineNumber = 1;
echo ("in if");
}
else
{
for($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++)
    {
    $lineNumber = mysql_result($lineNumberQueryResult, $i, "lineNumber");
    $lineNumber = $lineNumber + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use  mysql_num_rows rather than mysql_numrows and try.

Comment: `mysql_numrows` is not a PHP function use `mysql_num_rows` besides you should switch to Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Besides other comment(s); make sure you've also started the session. Use error reporting also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: See PHP's mysqli_ amd/or PDO APIs, and the proper use of prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(lineNumber) " .
          "FROM INVENTORY_BOOK " .
          "WHERE studentEmail = '$email'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

if($num_rows == 0)
{
$lineNumber = 1;
echo ("in if");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You issue here is that you use function that does not exist: `mysql_numrows()`. Instead you have to use `mysql_num_rows()`.

But the *real* issue here, and the reason why you wasted a lot of time, is that you apparently do not monitor your error log, even when you run into an issue. That should *always* be the first place to look at: your http servers error log file, that is where usually php errors are logged to. IN this case it would have told you that you are trying to use a function that does not exist. You could have solved this yourself.

A small side not: your are using an outdated database connector. The `mysql_...()` functions are deprecated. This means they will be removed in future. You should port your code to one of the more modern connectors `mysqli` or `PDO` and learn about the advantages of "prepared statements".

Comment: I have no idea why all but one answer was downvoted; including this one (and the deleted one). This and the other(s) have also "answered" the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do have an idea. I even know who down voted. And I am very happy to just smile about that :-)

Comment: Same here, on *all* counts ;-)